# Prevent right click in Safari browser

Tags: angularjs, safari, contextmenu, right-click

1. i am using Angular 10
2. i have html 5 video player & on full screen mode, i want to prevent right click,
3. by prevent right click i want to prevent user from download video, using right click, any user can download any video
4. here is my code

   ```
   <video width="100%" controls controlsList="nodownload" oncontextmenu="return false" preload="auto" playsinline>
       <source src="url" type="video/mp4">
           {{'Your browser does not support HTML5 video.'| translate:utilService.lang}}
   </video>
   ```
5. oncontectmenu is not working in full screen mode in Safari browser

> **so, how can i prevent right click in Safari Browser with HTML 5 Video**

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding it with CSS instead of cancelling the event:

```css
video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: it's not working, i mean in full screen mode still user can right click and download video